# How to delete an application in Linkedin?

Tags: linkedin-api

I created a Linkedin app long ago in order to allow users to sign in to my site. Now that the site is dead, I want to delete the app, how to do that?

There isn't a single article about that on LinkedIn, I contacted support, they couldn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps

Click on the app you want to delete and on the next page you will see the "Delete app" button.

Comment: it wasn't there last time I checked, they must have added it in the two last months, after I opened an issue about it with the support team. As always I might be mistaken, thank you.

Comment: They did change the developer interface yesterday, so that's probably it. Still, even though I can't remember, I'm sure it was possible to delete an app in the old interface as I have done it in the past.

Comment: Well at least I'm not crazy or stupid, if it was that simple i wouldn't have asked the question and it wouldn't have gotten upvoted nor stay for days unanswered. I really thought i was stupid at first :)